# How To add a Image on ToolBarManager

Tags: c#

I want to add a Imgae plz help me to do this i want to know which property is used to set image i am using UltraToolBarManager
[image]

Comment: It seems you are using a 3rd party component - you might get a quicker answer asking this question to the vendor or on the vendor forums.

Answer (score 0):

ultraToolbarsManager1.Ribbon.ApplicationMenuButtonImage = set the desired image here;